# Open android menu on a specific place

Tags: android, android-menu

I know how to make android menu using Java or XML and how to use or call but now I am facing a new situation i.e. I want to open menu in a specific place like when I click on image than menu pop-up on that image place.

How can I do it?

Comment: It is called contextmenu. Check the documentation regarding same.

Comment: ContextMenu is used when we long pressed on any button,image,etc. and it pop-ups like AlertDialog Menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code will help you to open popup at dynamic place:

```
public void showMenuPopUp(final View view, final Context mCtx ) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mCtx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_popup, null);
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.update();
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        Button btn1= (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button (new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 // button click event
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 0, 0);

}
```

Where view is your view on which you have to open popup

To open this popup on Image click write onClickLsitener of your Image like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // your code here
        showMenuPopUp(v,Activity.this);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162627/pop-up-window-from-actionbar-in-android Accepted Answer of this question is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23220300/1423203) , I used **PopUpWindow** in that example, you can also use **DialogFragment** but slightly minimum option,both supports custom layout which looks like menu. you can perform similar option on Button you clicked in your screen or the Actionbar button

You have two option two do this using popupwindow, on click of a button you can do  1)`showAsDropDown(findViewbyId(R.id.menuitem),0,0)` for popupwindow which is good cause it looks like it popped down from the button you clicked or

2)`showAtLocation()` which takes gravity property like **X** and **Y** positions, in which you can mention which place on the screen you want the menu to appear